# Outlook/Exchange allows some users to open a jar attachment

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, attachment

Using Windows SBS 2003 and Outlook 2007.

We just received an email virus in a jar file. For most users Outlook blocked the attachment as per usual, but unfortunately on one users computer this didn't happen.

- Tools -> Attachment Handling shows the security mode set to default.
- There are no strange entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security

Anyone got any other ideas on why this computer allowed the attachment to run?

Comment: Stop relying on Outlook to do this and get a decent anti-virus product instead.

Comment: Hi John. I probably should have mentioned that we do have anti virus on both the pcs and the firewall. However the file seems to escape detection. I uploaded it to VirusTotal and only 1 of 46 scanners correctly identified it. I was more thinking of outlooks response as a defense in depth measure. Given some number of viruses will always escape detection, why did Outlook let one computer execute the file?

Comment: Many an admin has gone mad trying to figure out why Outlook on machine A does one thing while using the exact same setup on machine B does something else. Outlook is notoriously unpredictable with these things and it's best not to rely on it doing the right thing and treat it as a bonus when it does. When all's said and done it is after all a mail client, not an anti-virus product.